# AngularJS $interpolate in Angular2+

Tags: angularjs, angular

Is there something similar to AngularJS $interpolate in Angular2+?

I would like to achieve this (in JS/TS code) but with Angular2+:

**EDIT**

> The main goal to achieve is to $interpolate string **without having**
>   **knowledge** of transform pipe which is used inside string to
>   interpolate.

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

var JsonTranslation = { 
  "txt1": "Cash {{ value | currency: 'USD'}}",
  "txt2": "Number {{ value | number: 3}}"
};

function myCtrl($scope, $interpolate) {
  $scope.txt1 = $interpolate(JsonTranslation.txt1)({value: 50000});
  $scope.txt2 = $interpolate(JsonTranslation.txt2)({value: 50000.123456});
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>{{txt1}}</div>  <!-- Cash USD50,000.00 -->
  <div>{{txt2}}</div>  <!-- Number 50,000.123 -->
</div>
```

Working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3nf7cza4/

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
`Cash ${this.currency.transform(value, 'USD')}`
```

Where `this.currency` is the injected pipe you want to use and `transform` is the function in the pipe which converts your value.

I assume `currency` is an angular pipe (can't remember if it is or not) so you'd simply inject it like so:

```
import {CurrencyPipe} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private currency: CurrencyPipe) {}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know which pipe will be used inside string to interpolate. That's the difference between a2+ and a1 where this knowledge wasn't required.

Comment: But you do know, you want to use currency.

Comment: This is just an example. In my translation json file I can have different pipes.

Comment: You should mention this in your question.